# Setup pipes inside wrapping bash script

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, pipe, child-process

Say I have a python program that I invoke as

```
python main.py
```

I want to wrap this program into a shell script called `execute` that may do some setup beforehand

```
#!/bin/bash

# Do something interesting
python main.py
```

Now let's say that I want to use pipes

```
./execute < inputData.txt > outputData.txt
```

How should I go about redirecting those pipes (or `|` pipes) to my python script?

Something like the below, but more generic (I don't know the names of my input and output files, or whether there is a pipe at all, maybe I just want stdin/stdout)

```
python main.py < inputData.txt > outputData.txt
```

A quick hack would be to just make my python executable and run that instead of wrapping it in a shell script, but I am more interested in learning about pipes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this particular case, you don't have to specify the pipes or redirection in your shell script.  Pipes and redirection change the standard input, output, and error handles.  Those handles are inherited by child processes unless you say otherwise.  So when you run `execute < input.txt`, the standard input handle for both `execute` and the `python` it executes will be connected to `input.txt`.  You only need to specify redirection or piping inside `execute` if you want to change what the caller of `execute` set up.

Note on terminology: `<`, `>`, and `>>` are [*redirection*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection) operators, not pipes.  Only `|` is a pipe.  The mechanisms are similar, but the pipe requires the shell to execute a new process.

**Edit** I do not know any way for a script to get the filenames associated with its stdin/stdout/stderr handles.  In the case of a pipe, there are no such filenames!

Also, bash has a [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) feature that is sort of a mix of pipes and redirection.  `execute < <(echo yes)` will run `echo yes`, and put its output in a special filename (e.g., `/dev/fd/42`).  The special filename goes on the command line.  So the result is like `echo yes > /dev/fd/42 ; execute < /dev/fd/42`.  This is useful when you don't want to create a new subshell, which `|` normally does.

Comment: THANK YOU! to the upvoter for pushing me over the line to 10k rep!  :D :D

Comment: Thank you yo much! That definitely helped. In hindsight my question was quite silly, which is why I did not find it asked on SO. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @AndreiCioara No such thing as a silly question :) .  Actually, answers like "you don't need to do anything special" are often hard to find, because the documentation usually tells you the default behaviour without explaining how it applies to different situations.  Happy hacking!